# shapeless Mapper for LabelledGeneric not found

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist, labelled-generic

I have basic type pool defined like that:

```
sealed trait Section
final case class Header(...) extends Section
final case class Customer(...) extends Section
final case class Supplier(...) extends Section
final case class Tech(...) extends Section
```

I'd like to present some case classes composed of types from this pool like this:

```
final case class ContractViewPartners(customer: Customer, supplier: Supplier)
final case class ContractView(header: Header, partners: ContractViewPartners, tech: Tech)
```

As they would be heavily used in feature-generators implemented via transfoming to `HList`s using method described [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes), I'd like to ensure that each field of presented type is one of

- `Section` subtype
- `HList` of `Section` subtypes
- record presentable as `HList` of `Section` subtypes

I've defined simple compile-time checker for this condition:

```
object traverseView extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseSection[S <: Section] = at[S](_ => ())

  implicit def caseSectionList[L <: HList]
  (implicit evt: ToTraversable.Aux[L, List, Section]) = at[L](_ => ())

  implicit def caseRecord[R, L <: HList]
  (implicit lgen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[R, L],
   trav: ToTraversable.Aux[L, List, Section]) = at[R](_ => ())
}

private def contractViewIsMultiSection(v: ContractView) =  {
  val gen = LabelledGeneric[ContractView].to(v)
  gen map traverseView
}
```

But it fails with (package names removed)

> could not find implicit value for parameter mapper:
>   Mapper[traverseView.type,::[Header with KeyTag[Symbol with
>   Tagged[String("header")],Header],::[ContractViewPartners with
>   KeyTag[Symbol with
>   Tagged[String("partners")],ContractViewPartners],::[Tech with
>   KeyTag[Symbol with Tagged[String("tech")],Tech],HNil]]]]

If i remove `partners` section from `ContractView` it's working and if i try to resolve `implicits` on `ContractViewPartners` they will be found too.

Again while writing question i've found solution with adding `.values` like that

```
private def contractViewIsMultiSection(v: ContractView) =  {
  val gen = LabelledGeneric[ContractView].to(v)
    .values //!!!
  gen map traverseView
}
```

Could it be that type `with KeyTag[...]` is not working properly as source for `LabelledGeneric` transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Case` is invariant, so the fact that you have a `Case` instance for `ContractViewPartners` doesn't mean that you have a case instance for `ContractViewPartners` with a type-level label (which is only a subtype of `ContractViewPartners`). You can fix this pretty straightforwardly by generating instances for e.g. `FieldType[K, ContractViewPartners]` (for some arbitrary `K`):

```
sealed trait Section
final case class Header(s: String) extends Section
final case class Customer(s: String) extends Section
final case class Supplier(s: String) extends Section
final case class Tech(s: String) extends Section

final case class ContractViewPartners(customer: Customer, supplier: Supplier)
final case class ContractView(header: Header, partners: ContractViewPartners, tech: Tech)

import shapeless._, labelled.FieldType, ops.hlist.ToList

object traverseView extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseSection[S <: Section] = at[S](_ => ())

  implicit def caseSectionList[K, L <: HList](implicit
    lub: ToList[L, Section] 
  ) = at[FieldType[K, L]](_ => ())

  implicit def caseRecord[K, C, L <: HList](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[C, L],
    lub: ToList[L, Section] 
  ) = at[FieldType[K, C]](_ => ())
}

private def contractViewIsMultiSection(v: ContractView) =  {
  val gen = LabelledGeneric[ContractView].to(v)
  gen map traverseView
}
```

You could also just use `Generic[ContractView]` in `contractViewIsMultiSection` if you don't care about the labels.

I would probably suggest not using `Poly1` for this kind of thing, though. If you just want evidence that the types are right, you could do that a little more cleanly with a custom type class.